# Can't find simulators with iOS version lower than 17 in run destinations on x code 15.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have recently installed X code on my 13 inch mac-book pro with macOS Ventura, The XCode version is 15.0.1.
I am able to create new simulator devices but with devices created with an iOS version lower than 17, eg. 14.0.1 the devices do not show up the run destinations list. I have checked the deployment target for my workspace and this doesn't seem to be the issue as it is set at 14.0.1. Has anyone here encountered a similar problem and what could be the issue?

As mentioned i have checked my deployment target for the project I am working on

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... this appears be a bug.

I updated to Xcode 15 ... downloaded iOS 17.0 and 16.4 Simulator Runtimes ... all iPads show up and can be selected with either version.

However, all iPhone simulators show only with iOS 17

So, not a perfect fix but to get the earlier simulators...

In the **Manage Run Detinations** window:

- select a Simulator you created with an earlier iOS version
- top-right is a DropDown list that likely currently shows **Automatic**
- change that to **Always**

That simulator device should now be selectable.