# Simulator with iOS 16.4 not appearing on Xcode versions 15.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator, xcode15

So I have updated to the latest Xcode version, and for the first 2 weeks, everything was working as expected. But today the simulators that I was using with iOS 16.4 disappeared.

I have also the Xcode 14.3.1 and there the simulators are appearing.
The only simulator i can see on Xcode 15.2 is with iOS 17.2

Did anyone else experience this and how can I fix it?

**Image from Xcode 15.2**

[image: Image from Xcode 15.2]

**Image from Xcode 14.3.1**

[image: Image from xcode 14.3.1]

**My simulators**

[image: My simulators]

I tried to uninstall Xcode and I tried to uninstall the simulators.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77438069/cant-find-simulators-with-ios-version-lower-than-17-in-run-destinations-on-x-co

Comment: I have a project in Xcode 15.2. The project has a deployment target of iOS 15.0. When I drop down the list of run targets, I see simulators for iOS 17.2, 17.0, 16.4, and 15.5.

Comment: What platforms are shown on the Platforms tab of the Xcode Settings window?

Comment: @HangarRash 16.4 and 17.2 are shown as installed in the platform tab.

Comment: @DonMag Unfortunately no, my simulators are marked to always show as run destinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From project settings, select your project target and open `General` tab. Then, choose a minimum deployment version that is lower than `iOS 16.4` like below:

[image]

Comment: It's odd that the OP accepted this as the solution. The question shows the same project opened in Xcode 14 with older simulators implying that the project already had an earlier deployment target. That shouldn't have changed when moving to Xcode 15.